# Remove in text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with split or remove text from filename..

If I have like this filename:

200726100_50-0002.JPG

230514008_60-0001.JPG

Result must be:
230514008_60.JPG
200726100_50.JPG

Or Im not using correctly split function?

Comment: `"230514008_60-0001.JPG".split("-")[0]+".jpg"`

Comment: Someone used split for hiding/removing text, so I tryed same http://jsfiddle.net/nKJWn/

Comment: But mine doesn't work..

Comment: @FreeNAS did you see my solution below? Is it ok?

Comment: Im tryng to figure out how to add your code :) @inanc

Comment: let me make it a function for you, wait :) @FreeNAS

Comment: @inanc Can you read my comment? :) How I can my path into var filenames = [ //Get files here.. ];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122585/discussion-between-inanc-and-free-nas).

Comment: Is writing all of the files to a php array and then feed to getExpectedFiles function work? Or, converting getExpectedFiles function to php would work?

Answer (score 1):

## You can do it with a simple `Array.map` and `regex` like this:

```js
// just add this function to your code

function getExpectedFilenames(filenames) {
  return filenames.map(function(filename) {
    var m = filename.match(/(\d{9}\_\d{2})-\d{4}(\.[A-z]+)/);
  
    if (m && m.length > 2) {
      return m[1] + m[2];
    } else {
      // or throw an error
      return filename;
    }
  });
}


// and use it like this:

var filenames = [
  '200726100_50-0002.JPG',
  '230514008_60-0001.JPG'
];

var expectedFilenames = getExpectedFilenames(filenames);

console.log("input filenames:", filenames);
console.log("output filenames:", expectedFilenames);
```

---

## Or with simple `Array.map` and `Array.split`:

```js
// just add this function to your code

function getExpectedFilenames(filenames) {
  return filenames.map(function(filename) {
    var s = filename.split('-');
    return s[0] +"."+ s[1].split('.')[1]
  });
}


// and use it like this:

var filenames = [
  '200726100_50-0002.JPG',
  '230514008_60-0001.JPG'
];


var expectedFilenames = getExpectedFilenames(filenames);

console.log("input filenames:", filenames);
console.log("output filenames:", expectedFilenames);
```

Comment: How I map all files from path? 
´var filenames = [
  //Get files here..
];´

Comment: Are files in an array? How do you getting them, can you post the code? @FreeNAS